# How to Extract the First Name and Last Name From an Email Address in google sheet

Tags: google-sheets

I have sheet document of inscription and I need to extract the First Name and the Last Name From an Email Address. I found some solutions like

```
=LEFT(A3, FIND("_", A3)-1)
```

but it just split the email address

[image: exemple]

but I need this output

[image: exemple]

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this if you know the delimiter between first and last name and you want them in the same cell: `=proper(TEXTJOIN(" ",,REGEXEXTRACT( A2,"(.*)_(.*)@")))`

Comment: the problem is that t_iddou@enst.dz the first name = iddou and last name = toufik but this module just split this user name (the image is an exemple)